# Relation "" already exist dynamic query

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to execute a query within a loop which is within another loop, which is within an anonymous code block.

I'm trying to run this query

```
query := 'CREATE VIEW hopsPartialDistance AS '
            ||'SELECT AvgDistance '
            ||'FROM Distance '
            ||'WHERE PlanetOrigin = ' || rHops.PlanetOrigin
            ||' AND PlanetDestination = ' || rHops.PlanetDestination; 
      EXECUTE query;
```

But I keep getting the error

> relation "hopspartialdistance" already exists

I then run

```
\d hopspartialdistance;
```

And the output is

> Did not find any relation named "hopspartialdistance".

So I don't know where the error is coming from.

Here's the full function

```
DO 
$$
DECLARE 
routeDistance real := 0.0;
hopDistance real := 0.0;
rRoute record;
rHops record;
query text := '';

BEGIN
  FOR rRoute IN 
  SELECT MonitoringKey FROM TradingRoute
  LOOP
    query := 'CREATE VIEW PortsOfCall AS '
            ||'SELECT PlanetID, VisitOrder '
            ||'FROM EnrichedCallsAt '
            ||'WHERE MonitoringKey = ' || rRoute.MonitoringKey
            ||' ORDER BY VisitOrder';  
    EXECUTE query;
    
    CREATE VIEW Hops AS
    SELECT A.PlanetID AS PlanetOrigin, 
    B.PLanetID AS PlanetDestination
    FROM PortsOfCall A INNER JOIN PortsOfCall B ON A.VisitOrder + 1 = B.VisitOrder;
    
    routeDistance = 0.0;
    
  

    FOR rHops IN 
    SELECT PlanetOrigin, PlanetDestination FROM Hops
    LOOP
      query := 'CREATE VIEW hopsPartialDistance AS '
            ||'SELECT AvgDistance '
            ||'FROM Distance '
            ||'WHERE PlanetOrigin = ' || rHops.PlanetOrigin
            ||' AND PlanetDestination = ' || rHops.PlanetDestination; 
      EXECUTE query;
  
      hopDistance = (SELECT SUM(AvgDistance) FROM  hopsPartialDistance) ;        
      routeDistance = routeDistance + hopDistance;

    END LOOP;
    INSERT INTO RouteLength (RouteMonitoringKey, RouteTotalDistance) 
    SELECT rRoute.MonitoringKey, routeDistance;

    DROP VIEW Hops
    CASCADE;

    DROP VIEW PortsOfCall
    CASCADE;

  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: And a `SELECT * FROM hopspartialdistance`?

Comment: @nbk Still says no relation exist

Comment: Pretty sure it has to do with: "... execurte a query within a loop which is within another loop, which is within an annonymous code block." . You will need to show the complete function, I'm betting you are doing `CREATE VIEW hopsPartialDistance ...` more then once in the function. FYI, no point in doing `hopsPartialDistance` as without it being double quoted it is going to be folded to all lower case per the error message: `hopspartialdistance`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've added the full code

Comment: you are looping and creating a new view with the same name over and over, and as this produces an error the code will rollback

Comment: @nbk but the PortsOfCall View has no problem

Comment: You don't `DROP VIEW hopsPartialDistance` like you do the other views, so it exists when the `DO` is run again.

Comment: FYI, you can do `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW ...` per [CREATE VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html).

Comment: Drop your view then excute your query